# Detecting elements margin-left on click is not working/not showing the right property? Why is that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a jquery image slider that is working based on left margin of the ul that holds the images so ul's width is image width * number of images. When i click next i want margin-left of the ul to be changed to marginleft-image width. The problem i have is with this piece of code.

```
next.click(function() {
    if (ml == 0) {
      carousel_canvas.css('margin-left', -iw);
    } else {
      carousel_canvas.css('margin-left', ml - iw);
    }
});
```

carousel_canvas is the ul, iw is the image width and ml is

```
ml = parseFloat(carousel_canvas.css('margin-left'));
```

Ok so in the beginnig margin-left is 0 and on click margin-left is updated to -iw. Then when I try to click next again nothing happens since ml is still equal to 0 and in inspector it's clearly updated. Why is it getting the wrong value for margin left?

EDIT: here's jsbin of my problem https://jsbin.com/dohejizica/edit?output

Comment: Please post a [mcve]